# how come the KM survival estimates per variable group look so weird yet we can use the variable in a cox model?

Tags: survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

I'm trying to follow the vignette [ggRandomForests](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggRandomForests/vignettes/randomForestSRC-Survival.pdf). They describe an attempt to explain cirrhosis survival by several variables. The KM survival estimates for the variable `Bilirubin`, grouped by quartile look like so:
[image: bilirubin]

Note how the relation is very weird - the survival for the lowest quartile is the worst, yet survival chances with 1.0 Bilirubin are much better than with 2.0!

Yet, they say that the `the final, biologically reasonable (cox proportional hazards) model` the researchers made had only 4 variables, and one of them was `log(Bilirubin)` with coefficient 0.879 with a very low stderr = 0.09.

wasn't that supposed to mean that there's a positive corelation and the higher your Bilirubin is, the likelier you are to die quickly? How comes that such a messy variable can be used in a simple monotonic model?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go to the original paper (or in the Fleming & Harrington book) to see the logic behind the model. I doubt that the KM plot above comes from the final model, as it shows a cleary non-linear effect. But this might be fixed after adding the other variables in the model.

The 0.879 coefficient means that the hazard ratio between individuals with a difference of 1 in log(bilirubin) is `exp(0.879)` which is around `2.4`, *given that the other covariates in the model are the same*, which is not the same interpretation if there were no other variables in the model (as would be representative of this plot).